# Git: copying a local repo to another folder

Tags: git, github

Say that I have a local git repo ("A") with a bunch of commits that I don't want to publish.

If I copy everything that is in this local repo "A" except for the git directory into a new folder (let's call it "B") and git init another repo there, is there any risk of this somehow messing up the first named local repo ("A") and losing the commit history for that repo?

Comment: You should edit your question and give dummy names to the two repos (e.g. A and B); that would make the question easier to understand.

Comment: @Jubobs How about now?

Comment: Much better. The answer is no. Copying the worktree of repo A to another folder B has no impact on repo A... Well, as long as folder B isn't nested into A.

Comment: No nesting. Thanks @Jubobs!

Answer (score 4):

The `.git` sub-directory turns a directory into a `git` repository. If you remove it (or copy everything but the `.git` subdirectory) then you have a project that is not a `git` repository and it's not linked to any `git` repository in any way.

Running `git init` in the "B" directory creates a new `git` repository that is not linked in any way to the original repository ("A") or any other repository.

But keep in mind that after `git init`, the "B" repository is a different project (with a fresh, empty history) than the old "A" repository and linking them (even possible) will generate duplicate commits and conflicts. (Thanks @NickVolynkin for pointing that out).

The usual solution when you have some commits you don't want to publish is to put them on a new branch and remember to not `push` it.

Comment: Linking them after an init will lead to a conflict. They will already have different history. With all other statements I completely agree and support. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin you are right. I mentioned your suggestion in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

### Copy with Archive Settings

From a parent directory:

```
cp -a repo-A repo-B
```

will make a duplicate repository that won't modify anything in A with the possible exception of atime (depending on your filesystem), which Git doesn't track anyway.

Both repositories will be functionally identical, including history and uncommitted work. You can then make whatever changes you like independently to either repository.

### Caveats

If you've cloned with the `--shared` flag, or set `.git/objects/info/alternates` you may have shared files between repositories even if you've created an archive copy. This is not the general case, but is an exception you must be aware of and take special precautions with if you've done this. *Caveat emptor.*

Comment: Note that the OP is only asking about copying the worktree: *except for the git directory*.

Comment: @Jubobs Don't overcomplicate things. Copy it, then delete the .git directory in one of the directories if you like. If you want to bike-shed and add complications like shell-specific extended globs to exclude patterns, feel free to post your own answer, but Occam's Razor applies here.

Comment: I'm not suggesting anything; I'm merely pointing out that the OP is asking about the consequences of copying the a repo's worktree somewhere else, not *how* to copy just that worktree.

Comment: @CodeGnome I didn't know about this, I will look more into it. Thanks!

Comment: cp -r ./old-directory ./new-path/new-directory